# Multiselect on change it shows value in alert but shows None when in ajax post request

Tags: jquery, django

```
$('.multiselect_region').change(function(){
         var region_list = $(this).val();
         var pathname = window.location.pathname;
         alert(region_list)
         $.ajax({
         url:"{% url 'sanjh:price_per_region' %}",
         method:"POST",
         data:{
         'regionList':region_list,
         'url':pathname,
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
          },
         success:function(data){
            console.log(data)
         },

         })
    });
```

It shows clicked value in alert but when I am trying to send it to my django view and trying to retrieve the region value with request.POST.get('regionList'), it shows none. but it prints the value of 'url' in this method.

```
class PricePerRegionView(View):
    def post(self,request):

        region_list = request.POST.getlist('regionList') #getlist or get,both prints None
        print('dsssssssssssssssssssssssssssss',region_list)

        path = request.POST.get('url')
        print('kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk',path)
        # if 'region_details' in r.json():
        #     print(r.json()['region_details'])
        return HttpResponse('s')
```

Comment: Please show html of your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to pass the javascript array `region_list` as a regular request parameter in your ajax call. You'll need to stringify it and the other parameters, and send them as JSON. For example:

```
$('.multiselect_region').change(function(){
    var region_list = $(this).val();
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    alert(region_list)

    $.ajax({
        url:"{% url 'sanjh:price_per_region' %}",
        method:"POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({  // Send the parameters as JSON
            'regionList':region_list,
            'url':pathname,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
        }),
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data)
        },
    })
});
```

And then in your view, you should load the JSON from the request body, and retrieve the `region_list` and other parameters from it:

```
import json

class PricePerRegionView(View):
    def post(self,request):
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
        region_list = data['regionList'] 
        print('dsssssssssssssssssssssssssssss',region_list)

        path = data['url']
        print('kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk',path)
        # if 'region_details' in r.json():
        #     print(r.json()['region_details'])
        return HttpResponse('s')
```